# AWS Lambda functions error: Handler missing on module after deployment with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I have a project that uses Serverless Framework to manage and deploy AWS services. In the `serverless.yml` file it is defined a state function and 3 Lambda functions in this way:

```
functions:
  FileUploading:
    handler: wesii_pipelines.handlers.file_uploading_handler
  InternalUploadEvent:
    handler: wesii_pipelines.handlers.internal_upload_event_handler
  GenerateTemporaryCreds:
    handler: wesii_pipelines.handlers.generate_temporary_s3_creds_handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: s3creds
          method: post

stepFunctions: ${file(serverless.sfn.yml)}

resources: ${file(serverless.resources.yml)}
```

and there are references to the three files `serverless.sfn.yml`, `serverless.resources.yml` and `serverless.env.yml`. The definitions of the 3 functions are contained in the `wesii_pipelines` folder inside the `handlers.py` file in this way:

```
def file_uploading_handler(event, context):
def internal_upload_event_handler(event, context):
def generate_temporary_s3_creds_handler(event, context):
```

After the last deployment (in which I tried to update the runtime version of Python for the Lambda functions from 3.7 to 3.11), every execution of the step-functions fails giving this error:

```
Handler 'file_uploading_handler' missing on module 'wesii_pipelines.handlers'
```

I haven't done any deploy in a year, so I have not changed any of the aws resources used by the project.

Even trying to redeploy with the old version of Python 3.7 gives me the same error, so this makes me think that something has changed in the way the Serverless Framework builds the deployment and associates the names of the Lambda Functions with their definitions.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: I just tried but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same:" Handler 'file_uploading_handler' missing on module 'wesii_pipelines/handlers'".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by updating the version of the serverless framework and related plugins used.